# Including local headers first

Tags: c, builds, include

So I read up on the [ordering of your includes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762568/c-c-include-file-order-best-practices), and this guy suggested you include your local header first so as to make sure it doesn't have prerequisites. Ok, I get that. I'm on board. The whole compartmentalization thing is good.

But I've got this file,  file.c which includes it's `file.h`, which declares functions to save files. Which passes around the `FILE*` type used by `fopen` and friends.

If I include `file.h` before I include `stdio.h` then there's an obvious parsing error when it's building `file.h` because it doesn't know about the `FILE*` type.

I know I've got to be missing something dirt simple, but I can formulate this into something google can use. Should I be doing something different in `file.h`? Is this simply something that needs to be included in a specific order? Thoughts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If a header file such as `file.h` depends on other headers such as `stdio.h`, then `file.h` should `#include` those headers as necessary.

Each header file should keep track of its own dependencies, and use `#include` guards to prevent multiple translation if it winds up being included several times:

```
#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H

#include <stdio.h>
...
void myfunc(FILE *);
...
#endif
```

This way the order of the includes simply *doesn't matter*, which makes maintenance *much* less crazy-making.

Comment: Macro guarding is always that way to go for things like this. Just make sure you don't accidentally double up on the macro guard names.

Comment: I've seen arguments that headers should *not* `#include` headers that they depend on; rather, that the `.c` file should directly include everything that its headers depend on, in the correct order. These arguments, IMHO, are wrong.

Comment: @KeithThompson: The people making those arguments obviously haven't wasted the better part of an afternoon trying to get 15 to 20 different headers in *just* the right order to get something to compile (with no documentation, naturally).

Comment: @JohnBode: As I recall, the argument had to do with avoiding the overhead of scanning headers multiple times. Even with include guards, it does take some time to read a header file. The argument was more valid in the past, with slower machines -- but even then I'm skeptical that the time saved in compilation would exceed the time wasted keeping all the dependencies straight.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Well, it's a point; I have worked on systems where build times took upwards of several hours, and if you're scanning the same file dozens or hundreds of times, I can see where there would be a real gain in not doing so.  But frankly, I'll trade the increased build time for the decreased maintenance time.

Comment: Augment with this with the rule that **x.c always includes x.h first**  This ensures that each header file stands alone.

Comment: @JohnBode: I believe most modern compilers explicitly recognise the "include guard" pattern the first time the file is scanned, and cache that fact to avoid having to scan the same include file repeatedly.